# Export KB articles from Confluence using REST API and Python

Tags: python, rest, confluence

I have a requirement to export the Knowledge Base articles from Confluence using REST API.

I have not found any relevant documentation as of now or any code that would guide me to that direction.

Is there any way we can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can start with:

```
        from atlassian import Confluence

        confurl = "confluence url"
        confkey = "confluence token"

        #username = "confluence username"
        #password = "confluence password"

        cql_query = "ssl certificate with san"




        ### Load confluence and grab the results using Confluence query language

        confluence = Confluence(url=confurl,token=confkey, verify_ssl=False)  ### You can use username=username,password=password or token=token
        start = 0
        limit = 2
        results = confluence.cql(cql=f'text ~ "{cql_query}"', limit=limit)['results']

        output = ''
        for result in results:
            ### get results with title, url and html
            page_id = result['content']['id']
            page_content = confluence.get_page_by_id(page_id, expand='body.storage')
            url = self.confurl+page_content['_links']['webui']
            html = page_content['body']['storage']['value']
            title = page_content['title']
            
            ### Send back lines of titles and urls
            #output += f"Title: {title}\n Url: {url}\n\n"

            ### Or send back the html

            output += f"Title: {title}\n Url: {url}\n Body: {html}\n"
```

Get the module from: https://pypi.org/project/atlassian-python-api/

Have a playaround with the Confluence object to see what other methods you can use. I used CQL but you can choose to retrieve all pages from a particular confluence space, or retrieve a page by ID.... Up to you :)

Obviously it goes without saying: take care of your sensitive credentials, bla bla bla